# Look up table price extrapolation for future

Tags: python, pandas, tiling

I have a problem that requires looking up the prices for products with a slight twist.

Product sold table

```
Date    Prod_1  Prod_2  Prod_3
5/1/2020    0   0   0
6/1/2020    0   0   0
7/1/2020    0   0   0
8/1/2020    100 1,000   50
9/1/2020    120 1,100   100
10/1/2020   140 1,200   150
11/1/2020   160 1,300   200
12/1/2020   180 1,400   250
1/1/2021    200 1,500   300
2/1/2021    220 1,600   350
3/1/2021    240 1,700   400
4/1/2021    260 1,800   450
5/1/2021    280 1,900   500
6/1/2021    300 2,000   550
```

The price table looks like this

```
Date    Prod_1  Prod_2  Prod_3
8/1/2020    50  10  2.00
9/1/2020    55  11  2.50
10/1/2020   56  12  2.65
11/1/2020   58  13  2.70
12/1/2020   60  14  2.80
1/1/2021    10  10  1.00
```

I want to compute something that will look up the price for each product depending on the date. If the price data does not contain the date, it simply uses the last price in the table. I have tried indexing on Date and reindexing to multiply but can't seem to get it right.

Final output should be something like this

```
Date    Rev_Prod_1  Rev_Prod_2  Rev_Prod_3
5/1/2020    0   0   0
6/1/2020    0   0   0
7/1/2020    0   0   0
8/1/2020    5,000   10,000  100
9/1/2020    6,600   12,100  250
10/1/2020   7,840   14,400  398
11/1/2020   9,280   16,900  540
12/1/2020   10,800  19,600  700
1/1/2021    2,000   15,000  300
2/1/2021    2,200   15,000  350
3/1/2021    2,400   16,000  400
4/1/2021    2,600   17,000  450
5/1/2021    2,800   18,000  500
6/1/2021    3,000   19,000  550
```

what I have so far is able to join the tables on dates

```
prod_data = pd.read_csv('../Product_sold.csv')
prod_data.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
price_data = pd.read_csv('../Product_cost.csv')
price_data.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
prod_data_comb = prod_data.join(price_data)
```

which produces the output

```
           Prod_1 Prod_2  Prod_3  Prod_1_Pr  Prod_2_Pr  Prod_3_Pr
Date                                                             
5/1/2020        0      0       0        NaN        NaN        NaN
6/1/2020        0      0       0        NaN        NaN        NaN
7/1/2020        0      0       0        NaN        NaN        NaN
8/1/2020      100  1,000      50       50.0       10.0       2.00
9/1/2020      120  1,100     100       55.0       11.0       2.50
10/1/2020     140  1,200     150       56.0       12.0       2.65
11/1/2020     160  1,300     200       58.0       13.0       2.70
12/1/2020     180  1,400     250       60.0       14.0       2.80
1/1/2021      200  1,500     300       10.0       10.0       1.00
2/1/2021      220  1,600     350        NaN        NaN        NaN
3/1/2021      240  1,700     400        NaN        NaN        NaN
4/1/2021      260  1,800     450        NaN        NaN        NaN
5/1/2021      280  1,900     500        NaN        NaN        NaN
6/1/2021      300  2,000     550        NaN        NaN        NaN
```

from which I can multiply but I want the prices after the data 1/1/2021 to be same as 1/1/2021 for multiplication.

Comment: whats the expected output table?

Comment: have a look at `merge_asof`

Comment: Please give a [mcve] of what you tried.

Comment: Just added the code I have so far at this moment.

Comment: prod_data_comb = pd.merge_asof(prod_data, price_data, on='Date') . This one worked. Thanks